# scala -> java getField().get()

Tags: java, android, scala, reflection

So i am trying to shorten my android project R calls, basically to reduce code related to R. So i want to do something like

```scala
object App extends Application {
  def string(field : String) : String = {
    this.getResources().getString(R.string.getClass().getField(field).get())}
  }
```

in order to change `App.getResources().getString(R.string.someAndroidValueString)`
to `App.string("someAndroidValueString")`

yeah, that isnt really short, but from there i could create some traits so that model classes should only define a methood *resourceName()*, and there would be no calls to R anywhere (except in the traits, i guess)

i can get the declared fields from R.string.declaredField (thanks to a comment down here), but i get many erros depending of the argument of *get* in `field.get()`.

In order to get this idea to work, i need to get the value from that field.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Not my field, but `getField` returns public fields, `getDeclaredField` will include your private scala field.

Comment: That resolves half of the problem!! Thank! Now waiting for the other half :P

Comment: Please think about it before you go this way. It looks like you're switching from referencing `R` fields explicitly to referencing them indirectly via strings. What happens if you type "someAdroidValueString" in your approach?

Comment: You mean that i may misspell the string and then i get a BOOM! in the application? yeah, i know working with strings that way is dangerous. I just was trying to extract some code in a trait so model classes can implement myResName or something, and then never getting to see any more code related to R. It is not the solution, but it is the only i came up with.

Comment: Yes, exactly, glad you got my point! So it turns out that the problem is actually something about reducing boilerplate code related to `R`. If you could edit your question to conform to that, i.e. describing the current usage scenario `R` and the desired effects, it might be more likely to get an answer you need. Also, please use "@" when replying to a comment that does not originate from the post's author. I only saw your reply by chance.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is strictly to reduce boilerplate, then just use import.  You won't lose type checking and risk typos in your strings.

```
import App.getResources._
import R.string._
getString(someAndroidValueString)
```

Not 100% sure the first import is valid because I don't know what `getResources` is, but try it.

Comment: Almost, someAndroidValueString is still a variable, i cannot generalize it with a string. What i was looking for was getString("someAndroidValue")

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work as i wanted.
The thing that was troubling me was the *get* argument. As i understand it, the argument is supposed to be an instance, any instance of the same object's class i want to get the field's value. 
So the answer :

```
this.getResources().getString(
    classOf[R.string].getDeclaredField(fieldName).getInt(classOf[R].newInstance()))
```

and with that, i got what i was looking for.

Comment: The thing with this solution is that right now, i can pass any object to getInt() and i am still getting it to work, while a day ago the same code wasnt working, so i dont think this is the right way either